# Get updated array length

Tags: apache-flex

I am trying to get the length of an array through mxml (not actionscript). I have the following:

```
<s:Application 
xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
>


<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[


        [Bindable]
        public var rivers:Array = ["Nile", "Amazon", "Yangtze", "Mississippi"];



        protected function remove(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            rivers.pop();
            test2.text = String( rivers.length );

        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:VGroup>

<mx:Text id="test1" text="{rivers.length}" color="red"/>
<mx:LinkButton label="remove Item" click="remove(event)" />

<mx:Text id="test2" color="blue"/>  

</s:VGroup>

</s:Application>
```

Why does test2 show the correct array length but test1 is stale?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use bindings to display rivers length property in test1.
The thing is your collection is an Array.
Array doesn't dispatch events when it changes that's why the binding is never trigged.

Use a ArrayCollection instance instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
    [Bindable]
    var len:String = "0";
    [Bindable]
    public var rivers:ArrayCollection = ["Nile", "Amazon", "Yangtze", "Mississippi"];

    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
                protected function remove(event:MouseEvent):void {
                    rivers.removeItemAt(0);
                    len = String( rivers.length );

                }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>

    <mx:Text id="test1" text="{len}" color="red"/>
    <mx:LinkButton label="remove Item" click="remove(event)" />

    <mx:Text id="test2" color="blue"/>
```